# Add drop shadow to png image

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I want to add a drop shadow to a png image (image with alpha) in flutter.

I've already tried using BoxShadow, but I don't want to have a box shadow. I need a shadow that adapts to the png image.

Desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, you need two images, change the color of one them(your images should be transparent to make this happen) like:

```
child: Image.asset("assets/cat.png", color:Colors.black,),
```

Then put black one to the background using **Stack** and change its position to match shadow position.

Then add **BackdropFilter** to black one.

I think will work.

Code:

```
Stack(children: [
    Opacity(child: Image.asset(imagePath, color: Colors.black), opacity: 0.2),
    ClipRect(child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
        child: Image.asset(imagePath)))
])
```

Comment: glad to hear :)

Comment: Is this the only to do that?

Comment: It  blurs the background, unfortunately, so not the ideal solution if you have graphics in the background of your app. But better than nothing, I guess... I don't know the better way to do it, other than dropping the shadow in Photoshop and then embedding the image.

Answer (score 8):

Try this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/simple_shadow

It's very configurable, and this is an example:

```
Container(
              child: SimpleShadow(
                child: Image(
                  width: 70.0,
                  height: 70.0,
                  image: NetworkImage(logoUrl),
                  semanticLabel: title,
                ),
                opacity: 0.25, // Default: 0.5
                color: Colors.black, // Default: Black
                offset: Offset(3, 3), // Default: Offset(2, 2)
                sigma: 7, // Default: 2
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Kudos to @marcelo below for authoring this package :)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this same issue with SVG images, so I developed a solution for any widget, I hope it help you.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Transform.translate(
      offset: offset,
      child: ImageFiltered(
        imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: sigma, sigmaX: sigma),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: 0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ColorFiltered(
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcATop),
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    child,
  ],
)
```

I've also uploaded a package in Pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/simple_shadow